# SCSS/SASS removing CSS line on the output?

Tags: sass, node-sass

I'm trying to understand why a line on my .scss file was removed from the resulting .css file.

SCSS file:

```
.grid1 {
  display: -ms-grid;  // Why is this removed from the output?
  display: grid;
}
.grid2 {
  display: grid;
  display: -ms-grid;  // although nothing is removed here (as I expected)
}
```

Result:

```
.grid1 {
  display: grid; }

.grid2 {
  display: grid;
  display: -ms-grid; }
```

I'm using [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) 4.14.1 if that matters

**EDIT:**

It's apparently because we exclude IE in the [browserslist](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist) in our package.json, so it's not a SASS thing.

Thanks guys for the answers

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are changing the value of the `display` tag for `.grid1` with `display: grid` on the next line of the code for `.grid1`. Because of that try having the line `display: -ms-grid` after the `display :grid`.

Let me explain your code:

```
.grid1 {
  display: -ms-grid; /* Here this line is being ignored as its value is changed on the next line of the code */
  display: grid;

}
.grid2 {
  display: grid;  /* Here this line is being ignored as its value is changed on the next line of the code */
  display: -ms-grid;
}
```

Note that actually the same (ignoring of the first `display:..` line as well in `.grid2`. By that I mean that in `.grid2`, `display: grid` is being ignored since `SCSS` knows that display will have a change of value on the next line.

Comment: I know that thanks, that's why I made `.grid2` for comparison.
But why did it remove it on `.grid1` but doesn't remove anything on `.grid2`?

Comment: In that case would you mind pasting your full code? Because probably something else is interfering here with `.grid1` css style formatting

Comment: It is the full code on the original question. This is not a "how to" question, it's a "why" question. I just want to understand  :)

Comment: Think it like when you type `display: -ms-grid` it sets the value of the variable `display` to `-ms-grid`, and when you write another line saying that `display: grid` it changes the value of the  variable `display` to `grid` and then that makes the previous line to have no effect. Just consider `display` to be a variable.

Comment: I modified my answer now, please do go and check it out. Hope it helps in understanding why SCSS ignores it

Answer (score 0):

My guess is because it expects the vendor prefixed style rule to be first, if it exists at all, based on the way the different browsers expect the rules. Since most of the browsers know how to interpret `display: grid`, it throws out the `display: -ms-grid` unless you specifically force the browser to deal with it first.

Could also just be a bug in node-sass.